# Convert incoming string to dictionary/map javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I am new `javascript`. I could do this in 2 seconds in python/java but I am struggling here. I am developing an `reactJS` app. I am retrieving a string which is a dictionary/`HashMap<String, ArrayList>` from a server via `axios`. I get `response.data` and my data is in the form:

```
{ "key1": [1,23,4,5,5,2], 
   "key2": [2,6,5,5,5,6,5],
   ...
}
```

I want to convert this into a map/dictionary so I can access it like so (get(), keys(), etc.

However, i am having trouble doing this.
`console.log(typeof data)` gives me `string`.

And when I `JSON.parse()` or `JSON.stringify()` and use `new Map()` i get this weird thing with thousands of integer keys and it doesn't act like I want. Any idea on how I can do this?

Thanks!

---

### EDIT

Here is a more complete code example.

```
const fetchData = () => {
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/pdata";
    const promise = axios.get(url);
    console.log(promise);
    const dataPromise = promise.then((response) => response.data);
    console.log(dataPromise);

    return dataPromise;
}
export default function Home() {

  //Bind the data to a useState Hook in React, to ensure that we have the correct data
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  //This function runs on page reload, twice. Your fetch data function will run repeatedly while contained 
  //within this functional component.
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((apiEndpoint) => {
      //setting data equal to the result of the FetchData function
      setData(apiEndpoint);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  // We now have the data. 
  // Convert it to a map
  const map = new Map(Object.entries(data));
  console.log(map.get("Model Used"));
  console.log([...map.keys()]);
```

At point `We now have the data`, `console.log(data)` prints the incoming data correctly its just is of type `string` not `map` or whatever javascript calls it.

Comment: Is your server response returning malformed JSON? It probably is since you said it was as string and you tried `JSON.parse` and you got an error saying it couldn't parse it. Otherwise, axios would have parsed the JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) and [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const obj = { "key1": [1,23,4,5,5,2], "key2": [2,6,5,5,5,6,5] };

const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));

console.log(map.get("key1"));
console.log([...map.keys()]);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I got a weird output. Its just an array of arrays with the same key. I tried doing this already and it didn't work. Anyother ideas?

Comment: The log shows the map entries which is what you need. You can use the map functions normally like ``map.get("key1")``...

Comment: So the keys are just integers. Its like its treating each character of the string as a value and assigning a key of an integer to each one.

Comment: So I tried with `"key1"` and it is `undefined` and the `.keys()` gives an array of thousands of integers. (My input is probably that many chars long)

Comment: Can you paste the complete code snippet that's causing this above?

Comment: Posted a more complete code

Comment: What does ``dataPromise`` log to?

Comment: What do you mean "log to"? The `console.log()` logs to the developers tab in a browser. That function is being called at an interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248001/discussion-between-majed-badawi-and-shavk-with-a-hoon).

Answer (score 0):

From https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-dictionary/

> Are there dictionaries in JavaScript? No, as of now JavaScript does not include a native “Dictionary” data type. However, Objects in JavaScript are quite flexible and can be used to create key-value pairs. These objects are quite similar to dictionaries and work alike.

It seems you can just parse the string that you obtained to JSON and use the parsed object obtained. For example:

```js
var api_response = `
{ 
    "key1": [1,23,4,5,5,2], 
    "key2": [2,6,5,5,5,6,5]
}`;

var parsed_data = JSON.parse(api_response);

console.log(Object.keys(parsed_data))
console.log(parsed_data["key2"])
console.log(parsed_data.key1)
```

Comment: I have tried this before and i got an `Unexpected end to JSON input`.  Thus, I changed it to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(api_response))` and its output is the same as if I did what @Majed Badawi says.

Comment: @ShavkwithaHoon I too had got it. There is a problem in the `json` that you had posted. There is an extra `,` (comma) in the ending of the array corresponding to `key1` in the json that you pasted in the description.

Comment: In the example, that I used above, I removed that extra `comma` assuming it might have got added by mistake while posting it here.

Comment: Yes teh comma was a  mistake but not in the code I am running so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you try it again using just `JSON.parse(data)` and not `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`, please?

Comment: “Insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.”

Comment: @ShavkwithaHoon Not sure what your quote is supposed to mean. You should try `JSON.parse(data)` and actually examine the error message so you know why it couldn't be parsed.